# C# Hash with Collision Domain

Tags: c#, search, encryption, hash

I am working on a project that encrypts a string, which is the easy part. The hard part is finding a method to hash the string before encryption that returns a value with a collision domain. That hash will be stored along with the encrypted string in a database table.

The reason for doing this is to create a subset to decrypt when needing to search for a single record. How can this be accomplished using C#?

Comment: What part do you need help with, creating the collision domain or creating the hash?

Comment: How many collisions are we talking here?  If the sole purpose is to check to make sure you only check unique hashes, you'd need a lot of collisions to make that check worth it.  Like Scott Chamberlain said in his answer, having the hash weakens the encryption because it leaks information to the bad guys.

Comment: Also, if you only need to check for collisions, then I'd recommend ONLY storing the hash.  If you need to get the value back out, then store a lookup table of hash -> encrypted data to avoid storing multiple blobs of encrypted data from the same plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you need help creating the collision domain, the easiest way to do it is write a function that transforms the string in to a new string that has a high collision chance then hash that new string for your lookup value.

```
private static int COLLISION_LENGTH = 5;
public static string CreateCollision(string oldValue)
{
    var chars = new char[COLLISION_LENGTH];

    for(int i = 0; i < oldValue.Length; i++)
    {
        chars[i % chars.Length] ^= oldValue[i];
    }

    return new String(chars);
}
```

You then just need to hash the output of `CreateCollision` with the hash algorithm of your choice, I recommend using a strong hash system like you would for a password like [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes(v=vs.110).aspx) and treat the hash like you would a password (you will need to use a fixed salt however) because this hash does leak information about the data you encrypted.

Adjust `COLLISION_LENGTH` as needed.

Comment: After thinking about it a bit more, I can actually use an implementation of Adler32 to compute the value. Does anyone know if Adler32 is reversible to find all possible combinations to create the same value?

Comment: It depends on the input, if the text has some fixed format and only a few words differ between the template and the result it may be possible to do a dictionary attack on the word locations to figure out what words go where to get the same result from the hash.

Comment: That definitely answers my question since we are dealing with personal identification numbers. I believe we are going to use System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm to generate the value which I think is implemented in dot net core.